# entity storage size in JPA

Tags: android, jpa

Is there anyway I can find the storage space a single entity takes in app engine datastore? In my app engine datastore connected android app, I want to put some storage space constraints on users. I can only do that once I can find way to get the storage size of entities in the datastore. Any help is most welcome

Comment: there is no such thing as a "JPA database". There is MySQL, H2, HSQLDB, MongoDB, etc. JPA doesn't tell you that info either, your database does. Better to consult the docs for your "app engine database" (whichever one that is ... AppEngine/Datastore, MySQL, etc)

Comment: Apologies for the semantics. I have edited my question. I have gone through the documentation. No where there is any mention of the storage space details available via any api.